# Create a discord channel with the discord API

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests, discord

i am trying to use discord api in python with requests, and right now I'm trying to create a channel

this is my code

```py
import requests
API_URL = "https://discord.com/api/v9"
res = requests.post(f"{API_URL}/guilds/{guild_id}/channels", data={"name": "my channel name", "permission_overwrites": [], "type": 0}, headers={"authorization": f"Bot {the_bot_token}", "Content-Type": "application/json"})
print(res.text)
```

but it gives me this response:

```
{"message": "400: Bad Request", "code": 0}
```

someone can help me?

Comment: Have you looked into using discord.py ? As a library it is excellent for wrapping the api into async python functions and is generally well done. Its unfortunate that support for it is ending, but with the new version of the API coming out next year all discord bots will have to be re-written pretty much :/

Comment: yes, i know discord.py but my intent was to be able to create a bot without using it

Comment: Roger - i know these types of comments often get on my nerves, so I understand - i unfortunately do not know an answer, but I would go over your request with a fine tooth comb. An out of place : or space could be the difference between a valid request being parsed and a bad format

Answer (score 1):

Well, Your code is wrong you Messed up on the requests Data

You should replace data to json

Here is the working Code

```
import requests
API_URL = "https://discord.com/api/v9"
res = requests.post(f"{API_URL}/guilds/{guild_id}/channels", json={"name": "my channel name", "permission_overwrites": [], "type": 0}, headers={"authorization": f"Bot {the_bot_token}", "Content-Type": "application/json"})
print(res.text)
```